# Android error "can't open file for reading" in LogCat in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I am writing an android program and I noticed while debugging in eclipse I see the error "can't open file for reading" in the LogCat. I assume this may have something to do with my manifest file but it seems like everything is in order. Does anyone know what this error could mean?

Comment: This is not enough information to diagnose what your problem is. Please expound on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately that is all the information I know really. This happens when I load my app..and all the error says is in LogCat in eclipse is "can't open file for reading". There is no stack trace. The app still runs perfectly fine. I am thinking it may be something in the manifest file that is setup incorrectly...would sending you the manifest file be of any help?

Comment: This is not a manifest problem. It is a application code problem most likely.